# Anything I can add to functions.php to make text widgets accept PHP?

Tags: php, widgets

Is there a way I can make text widgets accept PHP? Perhaps something I can add in to functions.php? I'm redesigning my site, and I was wondering why I didn't use widgets at all in my current design, but then I realized it was because I use a lot of PHP in there.

For example, one of the "widgets" is a tabbed content area, so I've got the HTML and JavaScript shell for the tabs, but then inside the tabs, I've got PHP calls for the most popular posts, the most recent posts, and the most recent comments. I can't do that with existing widgets.

Obviously I could use a plugin, but I'm trying to go light on plugins where possible. Is there something I can just add to functions.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP in text widgets involves using eval(), which is evil.

If you know PHP, stick with static sidebars.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but everyone makes it seems like if a theme isn't widget-ready, it's outdated. I have no problems with it though if it's currently the best way to go for what I need to do. Thanks!